# Retaining the pattern characters while splitting via Regex, Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, arrays, string

I have the following string

```
str="HelloWorld How areYou I AmFine"
```

I want this string into the following array

```
["Hello","World How are","You I Am", "Fine"]
```

I have been using the following regex, it splits correctly but it also omits the matching pattern, i also want to retain that pattern.
What i get is

```
str.split(/[a-z][A-Z]/)
 => ["Hell", "orld How ar", "ou I A", "ine"]
```

It omitts the matching pattern.

Can any one help me out how to retain these characters as well in the resulting array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three answers so far, each with a limitation: one is rails-only and breaks with underscore in original string, another is ruby 1.9 only, the third always has a potential error with its special character.  I really liked the split on zero-width assertion answer from @Alex Kliuchnikau, but the OP needs ruby 1.8 which doesn't support lookbehind.  There's an answer that uses only zero-width lookahead and works fine in 1.8 and 1.9 using [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-scan) instead of [#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-split).

```
str.scan /.*?[a-z](?=[A-Z]|$)/
=> ["Hello", "World How are", "You I Am", "Fine"]
```

Comment: +1 for the scan lookahead -- your solution is safer, faster, shorter, and better than mine.  :)

Answer (score 7):

In **Ruby 1.9** you can use [positive lookahead and positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (lookahead and lookbehind regex constructs are also called *zero-width assertions*). They match characters, but then give up the match and only return the result, thus you won't loose your border characters:

```
str.split /(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/
=> ["Hello", "World How are", "You I Am", "Fine"]
```

**Ruby 1.8** does not support lookahead/lookbehind constructs. I recommend to use ruby 1.9 if possible.

If you are forced to use ruby 1.8.7, I think regex won't help you and the best solution I can think of is to build a simple state machine: iterate over each character in your original string and build first string until you encounter border condition. Then build second string etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it gives me the following erro

`ruby-1.8.7-p302 > str="HelloWorld How areYou I AmFine"
 => "HelloWorld How areYou I AmFine" 
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > str.split /(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/
SyntaxError: compile error
(irb):987: undefined (?...) sequence: /(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/
 from (irb):987
 from :0`

Comment: So what would be the solution in 1.8? I have to use 1.8.7

Comment: I found the answer from one of my colleague, for 1.8.7, do the following.   

`str.underscore.split(/_/).each do |s|
 s.capitalize!
 end`

Comment: @alex-kliuchnikau you can do this 1.8 using #scan instead of #split. Then you don't need the lookbehind.

Answer (score -1):

I think this will do the job for you

```
str.underscore.split(/_/).each do |s| 
s.capitalize! 
end
```

Comment: Note for the future visitors: This will work for Rails and will not work for pure ruby code because `underscore` is a Rails-specific method.

Comment: Note for the future: This will work only if there aren't any underscores in the original text.

Comment: Note For Future: In my case, i have been using rails and the strings that i have been manipulating does not contains '_' but the concerns raised by @joelparkerhenderson and @Alex are absolutely valid and must be consider befor using `underscore` function. Thanks @joel and @Alex again.

Comment: @nadeem-yasin this answer you've accepted is not a nice one, suffering both special character bug and requiring rails library.

Comment: I agree with dbenhur; his scan lookahead is shorter, faster, and safer that this solution and than my proposed solutions. IMHO you should change to accept dbenhur's.